# Javascript, For loop: returned 'i' value is different from that is stored

Tags: javascript, for-loop, alert

In this loop the `alert(i)` alerts 12,and firebug displays **10** as the end result.

```
 for(var i=0;i<=10;i=i+2){
      document.write=i;
    }

    alert(i);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` gets incremented after every iteration of the loop. When it fails the condition `<= 10` the loop breaks:

```
0 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
2 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
4 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
6 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
8 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
10 => loop gets executed, i incremented with 2
12 => loop breaks => i remains at 12
```

Comment: Hey,but after the loop stops,firebug executes 10 that was my doubt.

Comment: Where does Firebug execute 10? Inside the loop `i` never exceeds 10, so if Firebug checks inside the loop 10 is the maximum value. When `i` gets raised to 12, the loop won't be entered.

Answer (score 4):

But it is correct.

At start `i=0`, then we are iterating and adding 2 in each loop.

When we reach 10, we are still inside the condition, so we do another loop. Now the `i==12`, but this condition will tell us to get out of the loop.

So after braking out of the loop `i==12`.

Look it as a code:

```
i==0 //inside loop
i==2 //inside loop
i==4 //inside loop
i==6 //inside loop
i==8 //inside loop
i==10 //inside loop - we will add 2 once more time
i==12 //we are outside the loop, because now i>10
```

Comment: Hey,but after the loop stops,firebug executes 10 that was my doubt.

Comment: And what were your expectations? Loop will write into the documents numbers: 0,2,4,6,8,10, and then alerts 12. What is your desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is going up in increments of 2.

0
2
4
6
8
10
12

10 is still 'less than OR equal to 10', so the for loop continues running one more time until it reaches 12, where the condition is no longer true.

Change your code to

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
  document.write=i;
}

alert(i);
```

Comment: Hey,but after the loop stops,firebug executes 10 that was my doubt.

Comment: What do you mean 'executes 10'?

Comment: after the loop ends the end result is 10 as shown in firebug.